# Ubuntu won't recover after hibernate mode

Tags: 12.04, hibernate

With Ubuntu 12.10 and a nvidia card, sometimes my monitor won't turn back on when the machine returns from hibernate mode.  Actually it may not be the monitor but the system won't recover so I have to reboot.  I tested the memory and that is working.  The hard-drive seems to be fine.  I usually run all the updates, hopefully an update will fix the problem.

Has anyone experienced this? It is intermittent, maybe two times a week after running it continuously.

Comment: Yes, with an AMD card, I'm sure its the kernel, seeing many post on this subject

Comment: AMD CPU yes?  Maybe that is it.

Comment: Graphics card, should have said AMD Catalyst ;)

Comment: Nvidia card, AMD GPU, interesting.  It is a Geforce2 something, older model about 6 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you, It's a workaround

> Hi! Finally after a long time of searching and messing around I have
>   figure out a temporary work around solution until this bug gets
>   patched in future kernel releases. Please see below:
>
> Use this script only if you have been experiencing issues with
>   resuming from standby/suspend in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the screen
>   remains lit but black when you wake your machine.
>
> - **Step 1:**
>     Open up a terminal and create a script file as follows:
>
>   `sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd`
> - **Step 2:**
>    
>     Copy the entire script below into the file you just created and save
>     it:
>
>   ```sh
>   #!/bin/sh
>   #inspired by http://art.ubuntuforums.org/showpost...0&postcount=19
>   #...and http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18...ot-working-bug
>   # tidied by tqzzaa :)
>   VERSION=1.1
>   DEV_LIST=/tmp/usb-dev-list
>   DRIVERS_DIR=/sys/bus/pci/drivers
>   DRIVERS="ehci xhci" # ehci_hcd, xhci_hcd
>   HEX="[[:xdigit:]]"
>   MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS=2
>   BIND_WAIT=0.1
>   unbindDev() {
>   echo -n > $DEV_LIST 2>/dev/null
>   for driver in $DRIVERS; do
>   DDIR=$DRIVERS_DIR/${driver}_hcd
>   for dev in `ls $DDIR 2>/dev/null | egrep "^$HEX+:$HEX+:$HEX"`; do
>   echo -n "$dev" > $DDIR/unbind
>   echo "$driver $dev" >> $DEV_LIST
>   done
>   #for bus in $EHCI_BUSES; do
>   echo -n $bus > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind
>   # done
>   done
>   }
>   bindDev() {
>   if [ -s $DEV_LIST ]; then
>   while read driver dev; do
>   DDIR=$DRIVERS_DIR/${driver}_hcd
>   #for bus in $EHCI_BUSES; do
>   echo -n $bus > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/bind
>   #done
>   while [ $((MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS)) -gt 0 ]; do
>   echo -n "$dev" > $DDIR/bind
>   if [ ! -L "$DDIR/$dev" ]; then
>   sleep $BIND_WAIT
>   else
>   break
>   fi
>   MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS=$((MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS-1))
>   done
>   done < $DEV_LIST
>   fi
>   rm $DEV_LIST 2>/dev/null
>   chvt 1
>   chvt 7
>   }
>   EHCI_BUSES="0000:00:1a.0 0000:00:1d.0"
>   case "$1" in
>   hibernate|suspend)
>   unbindDev;;
>   resume|thaw)
>   bindDev;;
>   esac
>   Step 3:
>   Give the script run permissions by typing:
>   sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd
>   ```
>
> This script should work or your money back guaranteed (Joking this is
>   open source project so use at own risk :P ), as it forces the graphic
>   card to reboot iself using a good old kick from chvt1 and chvt7
>   commands which simulate what I used to do manually using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to refresh the GUI.

Source: [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: So not doing that, but at least I know that others experienced the issue.

Comment: I use it myself and it works for me.